# Why are ordinal indicators considered letters?

Tags: c#, text-processing

It got my by surprise yesterday than [ordinal indicators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator) are considered letters. I thought letters were only `[a-zA-Z]`.

Why are they considered letters and not symbols?

```
    char.IsLetter('º'); // true
    char.IsLetter('ª'); // true
    char.IsLetter('°'); // false
    char.IsLetter('ᵗ'); // true
```

Is there any flag I can look for to detect that for example `ᵗ` is a superscript?

Out of curiosity, is there any other letter that is not in the `[a-zA-Z]` range?

Comment: My first name would like to have a word with you about your definition of "letter".

Comment: Because the 7-bit era is over and has been for half a lifetime.

Comment: Someone had to make decision about the implementation of `.IsLetter` so simply lookup the implementation or the documentation to make sure the method behaves as you expect it.

Comment: [Apparently](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d57/index.htm) it's part of the "Letter, Modifier [Lm]" unicode category. `CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory('ᵗ') == UnicodeCategory.ModifierLetter`

Comment: Thanks @CodesInChaos that is exactly what I was looking for, both the explanation and the way to detect it. If you put it as answer I will accept it.

Comment: Basic Unicode knowledge should be mandatory for any developer. Including me. Everyday I learn something new about Unicode. Even after reading [this article from Joel On Software](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html) years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.NET follows the unicode standard, just google for the character and *unicode* to find some helpful information.

- `'º'` is MASCULINE ORDINAL INDICATOR

  Part of the *Letter, Other [Lo]* category.
- `'ª'` is FEMININE ORDINAL INDICATOR

  Part of the *Letter, Other [Lo]* category.
- `'°'` is DEGREE SIGN

  Part of the *Symbol, Other [So]* category.
- `'ᵗ'` is MODIFIER LETTER SMALL T

  Part of the *Letter, Modifier [Lm]* category

You can check the unicode category using [`CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getunicodecategory.aspx) which returns a [`UnicodeCategory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory.aspx).

For example:

```
CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory('ᵗ') == UnicodeCategory.ModifierLetter
```